# Instagram API - get own posts for website

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I read through all the dev docs stuff at https://developers.facebook.com, but I found no simple solution to solve that one simple question. I want to display my own posts detail at my website. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using IG Basic Display API and the `GET /{user-id}/media` endpoint

You will need to build a Login flow which is described in the Get Started guide
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/media